# How does Django generates uuid?

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have a model in Django that uses uuid this way:

```
uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=uuid.uuid1)
```

The thing is, when I generated 2 objects, one after the other, I got this:

```
933e35c4-df1c-11e6-8a53-ace01055799e
```

And then:

```
933e35c5-df1c-11e6-8a53-ace01055799e
```

From what I know every uuid is generated at random, but the probability of collision is very low, how are they exactly generated when I get these 2 uuid that are almost the same? (it differs only in the last number of the first block) and how probable is this?. Is there a more secure way of doing this?

The thing is that I have a set of clients that each get a unique uuid by e-mail, if they could just change one character and get to another client's uuid that would be a problem.

Comment: It even says how it's generated in the first line of code you've quoted: Using the `uuid.uuid1` function whose code is present in your Python standard library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `uuid.uuid1`, which as the docs state:

> Generate a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time.

You should be using `uuid.uuid4`, which generates a *random* uuid.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `uuid.uuid1` to do it (that's your default value). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1):

> Generate a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time.
>   If node is not given, getnode() is used to obtain the hardware
>   address. If clock_seq is given, it is used as the sequence number;
>   otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen.

There are other algorithms, maybe `uuid4` is what you are looking for.